# Are Embeddings open functions?

Tags: general-topology, open-map

My book defines as topological embedding any continous injective function between topological spaces $i:X \mapsto Y$ such that $\forall E \subseteq X: E$ is open, $\exists F \subseteq Y : F$ is open and $E=i^{-1}(F)$. If that's the case, aren't all embeddings also open functions (that is they map open sets to open sets)? I thought so, in fact $E=i^{-1}(F) \implies i(E) = F$ which is, by definition, open. The problem is that then the book defines an "open embedding" as "an embedding that also happens to be an open function", so i guess that's not always the case. What am i doing wrong then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All inclusions of points in a topological space are embeddings, but rarely open.

Your mistake iis that “$E = i^{-1}(F) \implies i(E) = F$” is just not true. That would imply, that the entirety of $F$ is hit by $i$. But setting $E = X$ and $F = Y$, certainly $E = i^{-1}(F)$, but $i(E) = F$ would mean that $i$ is surjective in this case.

In general, you only have “$E ⊆ i^{-1} F \iff i(E) ⊆ F$”, which is basically the definition of inverse images and a very important fact.

If a map $i$ is surjective, then indeed $i(i-^{1})(F) = F$ for all subsets $F ⊆ Y$, so the implication “$E = i^{-1}(F) \implies i(E) = F$” is true in this case. So surjective embeddings are open, hence homeomorphisms. That’s what you discovered.

Comment: By the way, most sources I know of define topological embeddings to be maps of topological spaces that are homeomorphisms onto their image, which is, in my opinion, the better definition. To see that they are equivalent, check the concept of [initial topologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) and note that the subspace topology of a topological space is given by the initial topology of its inclusion map. Your definition basically says that embeddings are injective continuous maps, such that the sources carries the initial topology corresponding to it.

Comment: Thank you, i got it. I thought the inverse image of a set was defined only if said set was contained in the image, thus that every open set in Y was contained in the image of i, but it makes sense that this is not the case

Comment: @DottorMaelstrom See also my latest edit regarding this.

Comment: Just to add. An embedding is open **iff its image is open**. This is due to the fact that the Topology of its domain is initial and thus any open subset of it's domain is open in the codomain.